# Why ocamlfind cannot find installed library (camlp4)

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I have a OCaml library installed. To prove that I have this:

```
$ ~/.opam/bin/opam install camlp4
[NOTE] Package camlp4 is already installed (current version is 4.02+system).
```

And this:

```
$ ls `ocamlc -where`/camlp4*
Camlp4.cmi     Camlp4Bin.cmx  Camlp4Parsers   Camlp4Top.cmi      camlp4fulllib.a     camlp4lib.a     camlp4o.cma    camlp4orf.cma   camlp4prof.cmx  camlp4rf.cma
Camlp4Bin.cmi  Camlp4Bin.o    Camlp4Printers  Camlp4Top.cmo      camlp4fulllib.cma   camlp4lib.cma   camlp4of.cma   camlp4prof.cmi  camlp4prof.o
Camlp4Bin.cmo  Camlp4Filters  Camlp4Top       Camlp4_config.cmi  camlp4fulllib.cmxa  camlp4lib.cmxa  camlp4oof.cma  camlp4prof.cmo  camlp4r.cma
```

But when I try this, it fails to recognise the file

```
$ ocamlfind query camlp4
ocamlfind: Package `camlp4' not found
```

How can I enable it?

My `~/.ocamlinit` looks like this:

```
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;
#use "topfind";;
```

Comment: `~/.ocamlinit` is the initial file executed by the toplevel `ocaml` and has nothing to do with `ocamlfind`.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are good that you forget to activate your opam enviromnment with

```
 eval $(opam config env)
```

command. And you're trying to compile with your system compiler, i.e., a compiler installed by your system package manager